# How to debug a ssh tunnel

Tags: debugging, ssh, tunnel

I want to setup a simple ssh tunnel from a local machine to a machine on the internet.
I'm using

`ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N -p 12122 <username>@<hostname>`

Setup works fine (I think) cause ssh returs asking for the credentials, which I provide.

Then i do

`export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080`
and
`wget http://www.google.com`

Wget returns that the request has been sent to the proxy, but no data is received back.
What i need is a way to look at how ssh is processing the request....

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get more information out of your SSH connection for debugging, leave out the `-q` and `-f` options, and include `-vvv`:

```
ssh -D 8080 -vvv -N -p 12122 <username>@<hostname>
```

To address your actual problem, by using `ssh -D` you're essentially setting up a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy which I believe is not supported by default in wget.

You might have better luck with `curl` which provides SOCKS suport via the `--socks` option.

If you really really need to use wget, you'll have to recompile your own version to include socks support. There should be an option for `./configure` somewhere along the lines of `--with-socks`.

Alternatively, look into [tsock](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tsocks) which can intercept outgoing network connections and redirecting them through a SOCKS server.